# (Presto) SQL cross join two tables but only for a specific right column

Tags: sql, presto, cross-join

Let's say I have two tables: "calendar" and "sales", where the calendar table contains a date for every row (in yyyy-mm-dd format) and the sales table contains 3 columns, one with date, one with store name, one with quantity; like this:

```sql
calendar:

   date    
==========
2021-03-01
2021-03-02
2021-03-03
...


sales:

   date         store     quantity
==================================
2021-03-01        A           10
2021-03-01        B            6
2021-03-02        C           15
2021-03-04        A            8
...
```

As you can see from the 2nd table, if a store has 0 sales on a specific day, that row isn't present at all. What I'm trying to achieve, is a joint table that fills the gaps, e.g.:

```sql
sales:

   date         store     quantity
==================================
2021-03-01        A           10
2021-03-01        B            6
2021-03-01        C            0
2021-03-02        A            0
2021-03-02        B            0
2021-03-02        C           15
2021-03-03        A            0
2021-03-03        B            0
2021-03-03        C            0
...
```

The way I managed to do it, was like this:

```sql
SELECT c.date,
       s.store,
       t.sales
  FROM calendar c
  
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT store FROM sales) s
         
       LEFT JOIN sales t
       ON c.date = t.date
       AND s.store = t.store
```

However, this query performs a double read on table "sales", which I would like to avoid, since the data being scanned is relatively large.

Is there any way I can achieve this same result by performing just a single read on table "sales"?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to have a separate table called `stores`.  Then use this table for the query:

```
SELECT c.date, s.store, t.sales
FROM calendar c CROSS JOIN
     stores s LEFT JOIN 
     sales t
     ON c.date = t.date AND s.store = t.store;
```

With a single table this is tricky.  I can think of some optimizations, but none that would eliminate the scan.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it as well, and I guess I will have to do it like that. The only issue is that depending on  the selected start and end date, some stores should or should not be present. For example, if a store "X" opened on february but I select only january, store X should not appear in the results at all, even if all his "sales" value would be 0.

Comment: @wtfzambo . . . Sounds like the `stores` table should have the opening date.  You might find some other data that is appropriate at the `store` level as well.

Comment: Yeah I guess I should refactor the whole query starting from the stores table and then proceed from there